# call to class's set method is resulting in "Uncaught TypeError: session.issue is not a function"

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to call the set issue method for this Session class from outside the class, and it results in Uncaught TypeError: session.issue is not a function.  Could anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?  I'm still troubleshooting so there may be other errors in this code.  When console.log the object itself, immediately before attempting to access its issue method, it returns as follows:

```
Session {_useSessionStorage: false, _useLocalStorage: false, _useServerStorage: false, _mostUpToDate: null, _lastEdited: null, …}
_creation: 1602290317
_issue: null
_lastEdited: null
_lastOpened: null
_lines: null
_mostUpToDate: null
_useLocalStorage: false
_useServerStorage: false
_useSessionStorage: false
clearLines: (...)
creation: (...)
issue: (...)
lastEdited: (...)
lastOpened: (...)
lines: (...)
mostUpToDate: (...)
__proto__:
clearLines: (...)
constructor: class Session
creation: (...)
issue: (...)
lastEdited: (...)
lastOpened: (...)
lines: (...)
mostUpToDate: (...)
pullLocalData: ƒ pullLocalData()
pullSessionData: ƒ pullSessionData()
setLocalData: ƒ setLocalData(issue, lastOpened, lastEdited)
setServerData: ƒ setServerData(issue, lastOpened, lastEdited)
setSessionData: ƒ setSessionData(issue, lastOpened, lastEdited)
_pullLinesFromLocalStorage: ƒ _pullLinesFromLocalStorage()
_pullLinesFromServerDB: ƒ _pullLinesFromServerDB()
_pullLinesFromSessionStorage: ƒ _pullLinesFromSessionStorage()
_saveToLocalStorage: ƒ _saveToLocalStorage()
_saveToSessionStorage: ƒ _saveToSessionStorage()
_setData: ƒ _setData(issue, lastOpened, lastEdited)
_update: ƒ _update()
get clearLines: ƒ clearLines()
get creation: ƒ creation()
get issue: ƒ issue()
set issue: ƒ issue(newIssue)
get lastEdited: ƒ lastEdited()
get lastOpened: ƒ lastOpened()
get lines: ƒ lines()
set lines: ƒ lines(lines)
get mostUpToDate: ƒ mostUpToDate()
__proto__: Object
```

Here's the full class:

```
class Session {
    _useSessionStorage = false;
    _useLocalStorage = false;
    _useServerStorage = false;
    _mostUpToDate = null;
    _lastEdited = null;
    _lastOpened = null;
    _issue = null;
    _creation = null;
    _lines = null;

    constructor(creation) { this._creation = creation; }
    get creation()        { return this._creation; }
    get lastEdited()      { return this._lastEdited; }
    get lastOpened()      { return this._lastOpened; }
    set issue(newIssue)   { this._issue = newIssue; this._update(); }
    get issue()           { return this._issue; }
    get mostUpToDate()    { return this._mostUpToDate; }
    get clearLines()      { this._lines = null; }

    set lines(lines) {
        if (lines != this._lines) {
            this._lines = lines;
            this._update();
        }
    }

    get lines() {
        console.log("lines()", this._creation);
        this._lastOpened = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
        if (this._lines == []) {
            switch (this._mostUpToDate) {
                case "Session": this._pullLinesFromSessionStorage(); break;
                case "Local":   this._pullLinesFromLocalStorage();   break;
                case "Server":  this._pullLinesFromServerDB();       break;
            }
        }
        return this._lines;
    }

    //creation -> issue, lastOpened, lastEdited, lines
    pullSessionData() {
        const session = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(this._creation));
        this.setSessionData(session[0], session[1], session[2]);
    }

    pullLocalData() {
        const session = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this._creation));
        this.setLocalData(session[0], session[1], session[2]);
    }

    setSessionData(issue, lastOpened, lastEdited) {
        this._useSessionData = true;
        if (this._lastEdited == null || lastEdited >= this._lastEdited) {
            this._mostUpToDate = "Session";
            this._setData(issue, lastEdited, lastOpened);
        }
    }

    setLocalData(issue, lastOpened, lastEdited) {
        this._useLocalStorage = true;
        if (this._lastEdited == null || lastEdited >= this._lastEdited) {
            this._mostUpToDate = "Local";
            this._setData(issue, lastEdited, lastOpened);
        }
    }

    setServerData(issue, lastOpened, lastEdited) {
        this._useServerStorage = true;
        if (this._lastEdited == null || lastEdited > this._lastEdited) {
            this._mostUpToDate = "Server";
            this._setData(issue, lastEdited, lastOpened);
        }
    }

    //issue, lastOpened, lastEdited, lines
    _setData(issue, lastOpened, lastEdited) {
        this._issue = issue;
        this._lastEdited = lastEdited;
        this._lastOpened = lastOpened;
    }

    _update() {
        this._lastEdited = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
        if (this._useLocalStorage)   { this._saveToLocalStorage();   this._mostUpToDate = "Local"; }
        if (this._useSessionStorage) { this._saveToSessionStorage(); this._mostUpToDate = "Session"; }
    }

    _saveToSessionStorage() {
        sessionStorage.setItem(creation, JSON.stringify(this._issue, this._lastOpened, this._lastEdited, this._lines));
    }

    _saveToLocalStorage() {
        localStorage.setItem(creation, JSON.stringify(this._issue, this._lastOpened, this._lastEdited, this._lines));
    }

    _pullLinesFromSessionStorage() {
        this._lines = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(this._creation))[3];
    }

    _pullLinesFromLocalStorage() {
        this._lines = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this._creation))[3];
    }

    _pullLinesFromServerDB() {
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this Session class,

```
set issue(newIssue)   { this._issue = newIssue; this._update(); }
get issue()           { return this._issue; }
```

the above methods are getter and setter (denoted with `get` and `set`).
They should not be called directly like we call a function.  They are implicitly called when you assign value to the property `session.issue` like `session.issue = "Sample Issue"`, the setter method would be called.

While accessing the value with `session.issue`, the getter would be implicitly called.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  That makes sense.  I was calling it like object.issue(newIssue).